# Make Caliburn.micro show `.ToString()` in Comboboxes

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, caliburn.micro

In vanilla WPF, when I bind a collection of objects to a `ComboBox`, it displays the the string whatever `ToString()` of that object returns. However, `Caliburn.micro` shows a message `Cannot find view for...`. Since I have numerous `ComboBoxes`, it'd be tedious to use `DisplayMemberPath`. Is there any way to tinker with `Caliburn`'s `Convention Manager` to revert normal behavior for `comboboxes`?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, this was the order for drawing/templates in XAML (WPF and UWP):

- Draw Function of the object
- explicit template assigned to that instance
- template assigned to that type
- the result of .ToString()

If so my best guess is that the framework you are using somehow adds a Template targetting "object" as last entry. How about adding a template to object that just returns .ToString()? That would hopefully pre-empty any fallback template like this.